# Adjusting DIV element's MARGIN-TOP value by the HEIGHT of other fixed-positioned DIV (that changes by the browser window WIDTH)

Tags: html, dynamic, position, margin, fixed

Hello all the web editing professionals! I have a bit an “alternative” problem:::

First off, here is my webpage that I need help adjusting elements’ heights and margins with::: [**www.rebelrock.fi**](http://www.rebelrock.fi). Please open that webpage in another browser window first!

So there are three DIV elements with the parameter **position: fixed** there; The **MENU**, the **LOGO** and the **bottom FOOTER**.

My problem is with the **LOGO included DIV** (at the top of the page, right under the MENU) and the main page content **MARGIN-TOP positioning**.

So as the browser windows size (actually the WIDTH) is changed smaller, at one point the REBELROCK .png-file LOGO IMAGE at the fixed-positioned DIV above will start automatically adjusting the width and height of that logo image. And when the logo is getting smaller (both by WIDTH and HEIGHT), then the HEIGHT of the DIV – inside of which the logo is – will be getting smaller too – and that’s exactly how I want it to be.

However, the non-fixed main content that is scrollable vertically, and especially the MARGIN-TOP value of that content will NOT be adjusted by the changing height of the FIXED logo DIV above, causing there unwanted space between the fixed logo DIV and the main content of the page.

So my question is; **HOW CAN THE MARGIN-TOP VALUE OF THE MAIN CONTENT ELEMENT BE CHANGED IN RELATION TO THE CHANGING HEIGHT OF THAT LOGO DIV ABOVE IT**?

As You can see, the pages are by far not finished in almost any way but I first want to have all the basic HTML/CSS to be perfect until starting to add more specific detailed content to the website. The site itself was initially a template of ADOBE DREAMWEAVER but that’s not important here

I really hope someone here could help me.

Thank You in advance!

```
 Yours, Tommi Tiihonen
 e-mail: tommi.tiihonen@gmail.com
```

My webpage: [www.rebelrock.fi](http://www.rebelrock.fi)

Comment: Check http://rebelrock.fanclub.rocks/download.html

Comment: This is your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give The saurce code to change edits on your website

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222750/discussion-on-answer-by-unknown-name-adjusting-div-elements-margin-top-value-by).